# How to use class immediately before injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have some data in sql that need to initial before BuildWebHost.
Like this

```
public static void PrepareToken(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IValidationToken, ValidationToken>();
    //need to use ValidationToken to init data immediately.

    //services.Add...  Other class
}
```

I can write another class to do it. but I want to reuse ValidationToken.
I can't just new ValidationToken, Because the ValidationToken constructor like that:

```
private readonly ICacheManager _cacheManager;
private readonly IXXXXXRepository _XXXXXXXRepository;

private Dictionary<string, string> _validationToken = null;
private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

public ValidationToken(IXXXXXXXRepository XXXXXXXXRepository, ICacheManager cacheManager)
{
    _XXXXXXXRepository = XXXXXXXXRepository;
    _cacheManager = cacheManager;
}
```

Anyone has any pattern or idea to solve this problem?

Comment: _"The API have High traffic and high concurrency. If too many request in same time that will take all thread,This will cause sql connection can't not get thread to opened connect... So I want to get token list first And put it on memory cache"_ This comment of yours makes this an x-y-Question. Your problem is that your API does not scale to your requirements. So you can ask for band-aids as much as you want but you will always run into your _actual problem_ time after time.

Comment: @Fildor This application is not a stateless application, so if I need to prepare data for it, I prepared. But I think you are right. Thread not enough is the issue-based problem.. Although I initial data before host run. I still get time out in connection open.Because have no any thread could be used in this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that right after `services.Add~` because at that time, none of the services exist yet. The service collection only collects service *registrations*. It’s only later that the service collection is built into a service *provider* at which point you can resolve these services.

If you need to initialize this `ValidationToken`, then you should do that within its own constructor. That way, you can make sure that anything that depends on it will get an intialized token.

Alternatively, if you require the validation token to initialize *other* services, then you should make those services depend on the token properly and also have them initialize in their respective constructors.

---

If you need to initialize something before your web application starts, then do *after* building the web host but *before* starting the host. So your `Program.Main` may look like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // create and build the host to make the DI container available
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    // create a DI service scope in which the initialization can be done
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        // retrieve service and initialize whatever
        var token = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ValidationToken>();
        token.Initialize();
    }

    // start the host which spins up e.g. the ASP.NET Core web application
    host.Run();
}
```

This uses the generic HostBuilder from .NET Core 3.x. If you are still using the WebHostBuilder, then this will almost look identical to that; just operate on the returned WebHost instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
so... If I want to Initial this data before server provide services, I need to initial data before BuildWebHost right?
That's mean I can't use ValidationToken Class in there?
The batter way is write new initial method on Program main void?

Comment: Building the web hosts creates the service provider. If you need to initialize things before that, then you cannot rely on dependency injection here. What’s better depends on what you are actually trying to achieve. It’s not clear to me _why_ you need to run before building the web host.

Comment: Because the API need to validate token in every request. The API have High traffic and high concurrency.
If too many request in same time that will take all thread,This will cause sql connection can't not get thread to opened connect...
So I want to get token list first And put it on memory cache.

Comment: The API being the web application you are trying to start here? Then build the web host first but don’t *start* it yet. That way you can access services from DI but the application will not reply to requests yet.

Comment: @Cacha If it behaves as you describe, you have a different problem: Your API does not scale as it should. Don't put on band-aids. Solve your problem.

Comment: @poke Thanks a lot. This sample solve my problem thank you!!!